# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large when trying to plot a gz file

Tags: r

[enter image description here][1]The file has 785 variables and 42000 observations(it has pixel information).

d<-read.csv("train.csv.gz", header = TRUE)

plot(d)

When I use plot() in R the error :" Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" occurs.

This is what the data frame looks like.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbERo.jpg

Comment: You have 785 variables.  Not clear what you are plotting

Comment: Please make your code [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).